# iOS7 : how to set navigationItem property of UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationitem, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController that works perfectly in one of my iOS6 app. Now, I want to migrate this app to iOS7.

I had read the Apple docs, and it says the following :

```
Starting in iOS 7.0, you can use a search display 
controller with a navigation bar (an instance of 
the UINavigationBar class) by configuring the 
search display controller’s displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar 
and navigationItem properties.
```

displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar is pretty easy to set up. But the only clue I have for navigationItem is the following :

```
Important: The system raises an exception if you 
attempt to set the titleView property for a search 
display controller’s navigation item.
```

I can't seem to find example of how to set the navigationItem. How to I say to my navigationBar to embed my searchBar? Somebody can show me an example?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UISearchDisplayController creates and manages the navigation item needed to display the search bar in the navigation bar. You don't need to create your own, although you can access it via `searchDisplayController.navigationItem` *after* `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` has been set to YES (the navigationItem is created lazily)

When the view controller with the search display controller is asked for its navigationItem, the search display controller will return its item (which contains the search bar) instead of the view controller's.

Comment: Thank you for your time! But there must be something I didn't get, because it doesn't seems to work as easily as you describe. From my working ios6 code, apart deleting my UISearchBar and setting displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar to true, do I need other pieces of code? For instance, do I need to put manually the lazily created searchbar in the navigation bar, or is it all magic? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The navigation controller will ask the top-most view controller for its navigation item. If that view controller has a search display controller and `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` is YES, we use the search bar-enabled navigation bar that comes from the search display controller. And you don't want to delete the search bar, just remove it from the hierarchy... the bar still needs to exist.

Comment: If you continue to have issue, filing a bug with a small test case (and posting the radar number here) would be super helpful.